# Azure Function unable to use connection string with no Entity provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function system that's using a DAL dll. This dll uses entity framework to connect to a SQL database and is in the UnitOfWork format for our database first code.

In azure functions there isn't the standard "app.config" file to update with my connection string to my database. So I added it here in the Application Setting's GUI:

[image]

I have copied the code from the app.config by just taking the value from the config, converting the " values, and pasting it into the GUI.

```
 <add name="Entities" connectionString="<This is what I copied>" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

However, whenever I run the code, I get this error:

```
2016-10-14T12:39:44.248 C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: test
2016-10-14T12:39:44.265 Getting UnitOfWork
2016-10-14T12:39:44.607 Getting Repository
2016-10-14T12:39:44.639 ERROR The connection string 'Entities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."
```

So, typically the provider name would be the entity framework, but I don't know how to include that in the code. My question is, how do I connect with this connection string, and have an entity framework provider?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working without code-based configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework 6 or greater, have you tried using [Code-based configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx)?  Some sample implementation can be found here,

- http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-based-configuration.aspx
- [How to set connection in Entity Framework 6 using Code-Based Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891633/how-to-set-connection-in-entity-framework-6-using-code-based-configuration)

Comment: how can you do that using model from DB with edmx file?

Comment: @batmaci, would this work for your scenario? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355909/retrieving-fluent-configuration-programatically-without-instantiating-dbcontext/34356848#34356848

Comment: I have the same problem and I've a database first setup. I don't believe it is required to switch from this to make it work but guides explaining the precise manner of using connection strings on Azure Functions are dreadfully thin on the ground!